# Altium: How to change designator font when creating new library?

Tags: schematics, altium

I am creating a new schametic library in Altium Designer and wondering how can I change the text font of designators, pin names and pin numbers for all components in this library.

Comment: Have you asked Altium?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit tricky, but for single parts/components you can do that. You have to be in the SCH Library. Just go to "SCH List" in the panels.

[image]

A new Window should open. You have to change the mode from "View" to "Edit" and change the objects to "non-masked objects" at the top-left corner.

[image]

Afterwards, you can change every font, size and color of every parameter. For designators you just scoll down to "Designator" and in the "Properties"-panel the Font, Size and Color might be changed.

[image]

If you want to change all Fonts, just select "all components" and include only "Designators".

[image]

But I would NOT recommend doing it. Because if you add another component to you lib, you have to think about this process and change it every time. Same goes for parts and components that are from third-party.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly the font is set in your Altium preferences, not on a per-library basis.

Just checked, you can find it here:

[image]

Similar question asked here: http://www.edaboard.com/thread275975.html

Comment: this way can be used to change the font on the whole altium settings! However, I just want to change for a specific library ?

Comment: You're probably SOL @G.Zambrotta . Altium just uses its set system font when dropping components onto a schematic IIRC.